# How Compatible is Apache Cordova with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am about to start developing an iOS app that embeds a Cordova WebView and I would like to know how compatibles it is with the Swift programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cordova-ios library is written in Objective-C, but you can create Swift plugins. One thing to note is you must make your main plugin class accessible to Objective-C. See the example [here](https://github.com/edewit/cordova-plugin-hello/blob/swift/src%2Fios%2FHello.swift).

```
@objc(HWPHello) class Hello : CDVPlugin {
    func greet(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
        var message = command.arguments[0] as String

        var pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsString: "Hello \(message)")
        commandDelegate.sendPluginResult(pluginResult, callbackId:command.callbackId)
    }
}
```